# Android 6 permission Easy Permission library handle "Never check again"

Tags: android, permissions

Hi I'm Using Easy Permission library to handle android 6+ permission.

There is a method to call when "never ask again" is check

```
EasyPermissions.checkDeniedPermissionsNeverAskAgain
```

I dont know what parameter should we pass to the method

This is the method definition

```
public static boolean checkDeniedPermissionsNeverAskAgain(final Object object,
                                                              String rationale,
                                                              @StringRes int positiveButton,
                                                              @StringRes int negativeButton,
                                                              @Nullable DialogInterface.OnClickListener negativeButtonOnClickListener,
                                                              List<String> deniedPerms) {
        boolean shouldShowRationale;
        for (String perm : deniedPerms) {
            shouldShowRationale = shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(object, perm);
            if (!shouldShowRationale) {
                final Activity activity = getActivity(object);
                if (null == activity) {
                    return true;
                }

                AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                        .setMessage(rationale)
                        .setPositiveButton(positiveButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", activity.getPackageName(), null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                startAppSettingsScreen(object, intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(negativeButton, negativeButtonOnClickListener)
                        .create();
                dialog.show();

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

But how to we pass the `Stringres`. Any help is much appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just wants a resource value from your strings.xml file. So just pass something like `R.string.okay` and `R.string.cancel`. If you don't have a strings.xml file setup (you probably should) but could also use system defaults and pass `android.R.string.ok` and `android.R.string.cancel` to that method. There are several built in system strings like that. Look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string.html) if you're curious.